# Running 2 apps with hypercorn

Tags: python, fastapi, webdav, hypercorn

I'm trying to run `FastAPI` and `wsgidav` through a single hypercorn server.

According to the [documentation](https://pgjones.gitlab.io/hypercorn/how_to_guides/dispatch_apps.html) it should work like this:

```py
import hypercorn
import asyncio
from hypercorn.config import Config
from hypercorn.asyncio import serve
from hypercorn.middleware import DispatcherMiddleware, AsyncioWSGIMiddleware

from fastapi import FastAPI
from wsgidav import WsgiDavApp

def run(hypercorn_cfg):
    fastapi_app = FastAPI()
    // ...
    fastapi_app.mount("/", StaticFiles(directory=".../web/", html=True), name="public")

    dav_app = hypercorn.AsyncioWSGIMiddleware( WsgiDavApp({ ... }) )

    dispatcher = DispatcherMiddleware({
        '/dav': dav_app,
        '/': fastapi_app
    })

    asyncio.run(serve(dispatcher, hypercorn_cfg))
```

The config for `dav_app` looks like this:

```py
dav_cfg = {
        'host': '0.0.0.0',
        'port': 8000,
        'provider_mapping': {
            '/dav/': '/path/to/files'
        },
        "simple_dc": {
            "user_mapping": {
                "*": True
            }
        },
        "verbose": 3,
    }
```

Running either my webdav app or my fastAPI app in hypercorn works fine. My webdav app works fine both with and without the `AsyncioWSGIMiddleware` wrapper. However, putting webdav app into the dispatcher and running hypercorn on the dispatcher does not work at all. Instead, Hypercorn ends the startup process with a LifespanTimoutError:

```
hypercorn.utils.LifespanTimeoutError: Timeout whilst awaiting startup. \
    Your application may not support the ASGI Lifespan protocol correctly, \
    alternatively the startup_timeout configuration is incorrect.
```

FastAPI alone runs well in a dispatcher like this. For some reason I have to map it to empty string instead of `'/'`, though.

```py
dispatcher = DispatcherMiddleware({
    '': app
})
```

What am I missing? Shouldn't the WSGI Middleware take care of the lifespan protocol? Is there a bug in wsgidav?